# Is there a way to grab my location on one site and open another site on my location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm playing around with this html5 script that, right now, loads a globe that and you have to click on the globe to grab the location and it opens another site with a map on the location you clicked. Here is an example of the site with the globe:

http://parameter-pollution.github.io/webgl-ingress/demo/index.html

You'll see that when you click on the globe it opens the other site with the location you clicked on. Below is the html code that makes this all happen.

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
<title>Ingress WebGL</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html{
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
  }
  #universe{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  .ada_wheel{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 396px;
    width: 396px;
    margin-top: -198px;
    margin-left: -198px;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  #wheel_outer{
    animation-name: rotateLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotateLeft;
  }
  @keyframes rotateLeft{
    from {  transform:rotate(360deg); }
    to {  transform:rotate(0deg); }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes rotateLeft{
    from {  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
    to {  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
  }

  #wheel_inner{
    animation-name: rotateRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotateRight;
  }
  @keyframes rotateRight{
    from {  transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to {  transform:rotate(360deg); }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{
    from {  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to {  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
  }

  #border_gradient{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
  }
  #click_notify{
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:20%;
    color: white;
    font-size:2em;
    display:none;
  }
  #webgl_error{
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    display:none;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Detector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Tween.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myOrbit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myHUD.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    @coder paremeter-pollution / https://github.com/parameter-pollution/
  */

  //audio controls:
  var sounds={};

  var tweenStyle={};
  tweenStyle.opacity=1;
  var inner_wheel, outer_wheel, border_gradient, click_notify;

   // standard global variables
  var container, scene, camera, renderer, clock, controls, stats, projector;


  // custom global variables
  var middle_earth={x:0,y:0,z:0};
  var orbit;

  var earth;
  var earth_radius=50;
  var layers= new Array(10);
  var layer_distance=0.005;

  var hud;
  var hud_distance=30;

  var crosshairTrackingPoint;

  var randomPointInterval;

  var numberOfTextures=3;

  function init()
  {
    if(!Detector.webgl){  //check for webgl support
      document.getElementById('webgl_error').style.display="block";
      return;
    }

    sounds.aquiring_position=document.getElementById('aquiring_position');
    sounds.crosshair_locked=document.getElementById('crosshair_locked');
    sounds.logon_established=document.getElementById('logon_established');
    sounds.zoom_sound=document.getElementById('zoom_sound');
    sounds.downloading_latest_intel_package=document.getElementById('downloading_latest_intel_package');
    sounds.ambient_space=document.getElementById('ambient_space');

    inner_wheel=document.getElementById('wheel_inner');
    outer_wheel= document.getElementById('wheel_outer');
    border_gradient= document.getElementById('border_gradient');
    click_notify=document.getElementById('click_notify');

    clock = new THREE.Clock();

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // set up camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000);
    camera.up.set(0,0,1);

    //HUD
    hud = new myHUD(camera,hud_distance);

    crosshairTrackingPoint=new THREE.Vector3(25,25,25);

    //crosshair
    var crosshairGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 30, 30 ); 
    var crosshairMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/crosshair.png', null, textureLoadComplete), transparent:true } ); 
    crosshair = new THREE.Mesh(crosshairGeometry, crosshairMaterial);
    hud.addTracked(crosshair, crosshairTrackingPoint);

    //var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101010,0.5);
    //scene.add(ambientLight);

     // spotlight
    var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.4);
    spotlight.position.set(0,0,50);
    spotlight.angle=Math.PI/6;
    camera.add(spotlight);
/*
    var spotlight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.5, 40);
    spotlight2.position.set(0,0,30);
    spotlight2.exponent=0;
    camera.add(spotlight2);
*/
    // add the camera to the scene
    scene.add(camera);   

    orbit=new myOrbit( camera, middle_earth, 500, clock );    

    // create renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // render container
    container = document.getElementById( 'universe' );


    // attach renderer to the container div
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );       

    // sphere parameters: radius, segments along width, segments along height
    var earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( earth_radius, 64, 32 ); 
    var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/borders.jpg', null, textureLoadComplete) } ); 
    earth = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
    earth.rotation.set(Math.PI/2,0,0);


    // layers
    var layerMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/layer.png', null, textureLoadComplete), transparent:true, opacity: 0.6 } ); 


    //this function doesn't work when you start with adding layers with lower scale. but i have NO FUCKING IDEA why ^^
    //if you decide to change it around and find yourself changing it back again increase this counter: 3
    var scale=1+layer_distance*layers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
      layers[i] = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, layerMaterial);
      layers[i].scale.set( scale, scale, scale  );
      earth.add(layers[i]);
      scale -= layer_distance;
    }

    scene.add(earth);

    renderer.initWebGLObjects( scene );

    projector = new THREE.Projector();

    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );          
  }

  function textureLoadComplete(){
    numberOfTextures--;
    if( numberOfTextures === 0 ){ //all textures have been loaded, let's get this party started ;-)
      var delta=clock.getDelta();
      if( delta < 3000 ){ //make sure people with google fiber can also appreciate the loading animation ;-)
        setTimeout( function(){startAnimation()}, 3000-delta);
      }else{
        startAnimation();
      }

    }     
  }

  function startAnimation(){
    fadeOutLoading();
      orbit.tween_to_orbit( { distance: 200}, 4000, TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out, function(){
        playSound(sounds.aquiring_position);
        setTimeout( function(){
          playSound(sounds.logon_established);
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout( function(){click_notify.style.display="inline";}, 5000);
      });

    randomPointInterval = setInterval( generateRandomTrackingPoint , 2000);
    //start render loop
    animate();
  }

  function fadeOutLoading(){

    var fadeOutTween=new TWEEN.Tween(tweenStyle).to( {opacity: 0}, 4000);
    fadeOutTween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.In);
    fadeOutTween.onUpdate(function(){
      inner_wheel.style.opacity=tweenStyle.opacity;
      outer_wheel.style.opacity=tweenStyle.opacity;
    });
    fadeOutTween.onComplete(function(){
      inner_wheel.style.display="none";
      outer_wheel.style.display="none";
    });
    fadeOutTween.start();
  }

  function animate() 
  {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      render();   
  }

  function render() 
  { 

    TWEEN.update();

    orbit.update(); 

    hud.update();

    renderer.clear();    
    renderer.render( scene, orbit.camera );
  }

  function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( earth );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) { //bazinga, we found an intersection point
      orbit.fixAzimuth();
      orbit.autoRotate=false;
      window.clearInterval(randomPointInterval);
      randomPointInterval=null;

      hud.updateTrackingPoint( new THREE.Vector3(intersects[0].point.x, intersects[0].point.y, intersects[0].point.z) );

      var spherical=orbit.convertCartesionToSpherical( intersects[0].point );

      console.log("--lat------------long------");
      console.log(spherical.inclination,spherical.azimuth);
      var latitude=((spherical.inclination*180/Math.PI)-90)*(-1);
      var longitude=spherical.azimuth*180/Math.PI;
      if( longitude > 180 ){ longitude-=360 }
      console.log(latitude,longitude);


      // http://www.ingress.com/intel?ll=LA.ITUDE,LO.NGITUDE&z=9
      //http://www.ingress.com/intel?ll=48.729699,15.205459&z=20

      playSound(sounds.zoom_sound);
      playSound(sounds.downloading_latest_intel_package);

      click_notify.style.display="none"
      border_gradient.style.display="none";

      orbit.tween_to_orbit(spherical, 3000, TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut, function(){ 
        window.location.href="http://www.ingress.com/intel?ll="+latitude+","+longitude+"&z=6";  

        /*orbit.reset();

        hud.updateTrackingPoint(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
        if( randomPointInterval === null ) { randomPointInterval = setInterval( generateRandomTrackingPoint , 2000); };

        //TODO: this timeout should not be necessary         
        setTimeout( function(){
          border_gradient.style.display="inline";
          orbit.tween_to_orbit( { distance: 200}, 3000, TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out, function(){
            playSound(sounds.aquiring_position);
            setTimeout( function(){
              playSound(sounds.logon_established);
            }, 2000);
          });
        }, 50);*/ 
      });

    }
  }

  function onWindowResize( event ) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  }

  function generateRandomTrackingPoint(){
    var min_azimuth=orbit.spherical.azimuth-0.5;
    var max_azimuth=min_azimuth+Math.PI/2;
    var spherical={};
    spherical.azimuth = getRandomNumber(min_azimuth,max_azimuth);
    spherical.inclination = getRandomNumber( 0.4, Math.PI-0.4 );
    spherical.distance = earth_radius;

    playSound(crosshair_locked);

    var point=orbit.convertSphericalToCartesian(spherical);
    hud.updateTrackingPoint(new THREE.Vector3(point.x, point.y, point.z));
  }

  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  function playSound(sound){
    var newAudio=new Audio(sound.src);
    newAudio.play();
  }

  //chrome audio loop stops working randomly. this ugly hack fixes it
  function ambient_loop_hack(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      playSound(sounds.ambient_space);
      ambient_loop_hack(); 
    }, 5601 );
  }

  function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}

</script>
```

```
<img class="ada_wheel" id="wheel_outer" src="img/ada_wheel_outer.png">
<img class="ada_wheel" id="wheel_inner" src="img/ada_wheel_inner.png">
<img id="border_gradient" src="img/border_gradient.png">
<div id="click_notify">click somewhere on the planet!</div>
<div id="webgl_error">Sorry, your graphics card and/or webbrowser don't support WebGL!</div>
<div id="universe"></div>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-42384097-1', 'github.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<body onload="getLocation()">
```

I've tried using this example to grab the current location:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

and loading the function on load with this example:

http://html5hive.org/javascript-beginners-tutorial/

Is there any way to make this work where it loads the globe, grabs the location and then opens the other site with the map on the current location it grabbed from the globe? All without having to click on the globe.

This is the script I run to get the current users location coordiantes:

```
<body onload="getLocation()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>
```

Comment: A fiddle of this would be helpful. However, are you saying that your existing code successful gets the location value? If so, and since you're already using HTML5, can't you just store that value in localstorage and call the value when from the next page?

Comment: The next page isn't my domain. But right now the code pushes the location of where you click on the globe. I'd like to, after having asked for permission to access the users location, once they click allow, it redirects to the other site on that location.

Comment: In that case, this would depend almost entirely on the functionality of the second page (the one not on your domain). Is there any way that the second page will accept anything from your page?

Comment: The second page does accept user location. It displays a map. I don't know if you know of a way to do what I'm thinking about as of right now, but I know the other site (not mine) will allow you to open the map on a certain location using coordinates with a link like so (https://www.ingress.com/intel?ll=10.551176486503877,104.39897047042017&z=6) If you know how to open my site, get the user location, turn that into a url like the one I pasted, and then open that url automatically...i believe that would work :p :D

Comment: Okay...that will work. Redirecting to the ingress site with the correct URL (lat/long appended as a parameter) is easy assuming you can actually get the location you want to pass. Does your existing code at least do that?

Comment: I just edited my code to show you the script I run to get the current users coordinates. I don't know what to do once I have the info or how to redirect to the ingress site with the correct URL (lat/long appended as a parameter).

Comment: See my answer that includes your code and redirect using the Ingress URL you provided. You can change that as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that gets the users location and then redirects to the Ingress site with the right parameters:

```
    <button onclick="getLoc()">GET LOCATION</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLoc() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(redirectMe);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

}

function redirectMe(position) {
    document.location.href="https://www.ingress.com/intel?ll="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&z=6";
}

</script>
```

This: `position.coords.longitude` and this `position.coords.latitude` are variables created by the `navigator.geolocation` function. You're then calling them up in the second function. `document.location.href` redirects to a URL you specify.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ve0bwg24/4/